# Can you use a wildcard in getElementById?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following line of code:

```
document.getElementById("question_*").setAttribute("disabled", "false");
```

I want to use a form of wildcard for the element ID. The script is run and used by lots of different buttons, they all have ID's of question_`something` - is it possible to make this `setAttribute` to make the button enabled for various ID's?

```
<button id="question_1a" onClick="nextQuestion(this.id)" disabled>Next question</button>
```

EDIT:

I've switched to a classname as suggested. Buttons now are:

```
<button id="question_1a" class="nextButton" disabled>Next question</button>
```

I've added the following line to make this not disabled:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('nextButton').setAttribute("disabled", "false");
```

But I get: *Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'setAttribute'*

Comment: Why not use classes and `document.getElementsByClassName("class")`

Comment: Just be aware that `getElementsByClassName` requires IE9+

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can't use wildcards with `document.getElementById()`, you *can*, however, with `document.querySelectorAll()`:

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('button[id^="question_"]');
```

This, of course, requires a relatively up to date browser; on the other hand using a class-name (for example `question`) to associate those elements would allow you to use:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('question');
```

Or:

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('button.question');
```

> I tried doing this: `var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('nextButton').setAttribute("disabled", "false");` - but I get: Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'setAttribute'

That's because you can't modify the properties of a NodeList all at once, you can, however, use a `for (){...}` loop, or similar to do so:

Using `for(){...}`:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('question');
for (var i = 0, len = elems.length; i < len; i++){
    elems[i].disabled = false; // to make them all enabled
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/gP7wC/2/).

Or using forEach (up to date browsers):

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('question');
[].forEach.call(elems, function(a){
    a.disabled = false; // will make all elements enabled
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/gP7wC/3/).

References:

- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [CSS attribute-selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-substrings).
- [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById).
- [`document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName).
- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) <sup>[compatibility](http://quirksmode.org/dom/core/#t13)</sup>.
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelectorAll) <sup>[compatibility](http://quirksmode.org/dom/core/#t14)</sup>.
- [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
- [JavaScript `for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).

Comment: Thanks, I tried doing this: var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('nextButton').setAttribute("disabled", "false"); - but I get: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<NodeList> has no method 'setAttribute'

Comment: See the updates to the answer (using the `for (){...}` loop is easier,  and more compatible but, sadly, less sexy...)

Answer (score 3):

That's precisely what classes are for:

```
<button class="question" id="question_1a" onClick="nextQuestion(this.id)" disabled>Next question</button>
```

And

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("question");
for(var z=0;z<elems.length; z++){
   elems[z].setAttribute("disabled", "false")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility, if `querySelectorAll` or `getElementsByClassName` (could be shimmed in a similar manner) wasn't available and you wanted to match multiple IDs.

HTML

```
<button>Question</button>
<button id="question_1a">Question</button>
<button id="question_1b">Question</button>
<button id="question_1c">Question</button>
<button id="question_1d">Question</button>
<button id="question_2a">Question</button>
```

Javascript

```
function getElementsById(regex) {
    var tags = document.getElementsByTagName('*'),
        tagsLength = tags.length,
        matches = [],
        index,
        tag;

    for (index = 0; index < tagsLength; index += 1) {
        tag = tags[index];
        if (regex.test(tag.id)) {
            matches.push(tag);
        }
    }

    return matches;
}

console.log(getElementsById(/^question_1[a-z]?$/));
```

Output

```
[button#question_1a, button#question_1b, button#question_1c, button#question_1d]
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/VHDY2/)

Then you can iterate this array and set the attributes

And the `getElementsByclassName` shim

```
function getElementsByClassName(node, className) {
    var array = [],
        regex = new RegExp("(^| )" + className + "( |$)"),
        elements = node.getElementsByTagName("*"),
        length = elements.length,
        i = 0,
        element;

    while (i < length) {
        element = elements[i];
        if (regex.test(element.className)) {
            array.push(element);
        }

        i += 1;
    }

    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nope wildcard isn't supported. But to solve this problem you can use jQuery to do the same.

P. S. I will try to post code once I am back at desk

**Update**
agree David Thomas & Beemo's code hint that should solve your problem

Answer (score -1):

You can use JQuery `$("[id^='question_']")` selector to get all elements with an id starting by question_